# Super Messages and CloudPage impressions

Tags: marketing-cloud, pricing, cloudpage

According to the [Marketing Cloud Pricing model](http://www2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/mc_email_journey_pricing_sheet.pdf), each time a visitor accesses a published CloudPage, this visit is counted as an 'impression' and counts as a Super Message (usage fee), similar to sending an email, push notification or SMS message.

I note that Marketing Cloud doesn't insert a persistent cookie on published CloudPages, which begs the question, is an 'impression' counted each time a user agent (web browser) request is made to a page? If so, is there any control to prevent malicious users refreshing the page constantly or making several requests to a page? For example, I could set up a simple client-side script to make 1,000+ requests per hour to a CloudPage and rack up a pretty significant Super Message bill within a few hours for a poor unsuspecting Marketing Cloud account.

Previously, users could monitor their usage from the [3Sixty Portal](https://3sixty.exacttarget.com/) but this has been sunset and there doesn't appear to be any way to monitor usage, so I'm unable to clarify what the actual behavior is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you're correct. Every hit counts as an impression.

The monitoring team in Marketing Cloud will shut down a page if it's been accessed suspiciously. I know of a case with a large Australian client where they had a competition page that was shut down by the monitoring team because too many people were hitting the page; the monitoring team thought it was suspicious.

I'm not 100% sure if this is something they still do or if it's a guarantee.

Comment: If what you say is correct, then this is quite concerning. I can understand why Salesforce would choose to shut down a competition page if it's subject to a DDoS attack, but it would seem that this action is rather extreme for just a large volume of page visits. I would have assumed that if the page was being accessed maliciously then the offending IP address(es) would be blocked from accessing the page, rather than shutting down the entire competition page which would significantly impact the customer.

Comment: Absolutely. LIke I said, it's something that I know happened. It may have been because they saw repeated IPs hitting the page. In either case it means your hypothetical situation with a client-side script impossible (assuming the monitoring team still does this).

Comment: @EliotHarper This was not IP specific as both pages responded the same regardless of the machine or IP accessing them.